# Abstract Algebra: Rings and Units.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $u$ be a non-zero element of a simple, commutative, unital
ring $R$. Show that $u$ is a unit of the monoid $(R, *, 1)$.

I'm just really struggling to understand the concept of building or defining rings. This is an example exercise of something I was struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

The key condition is that $R$ is *simple*.

If I understand well, we want to show that $u$ is *invertible* in the multiplicative monoid of $R$ (i.e., is a 'unit' of the ring).

Consider the ideal $\,uR=\{ux\mid x\in R\}$, because $1\in R$ and $u\ne 0$ we have $uR\ne 0$. But as $R$ is simple (having only the two trivial ideals $\{0\}$ and $R$), we get that $uR=R$, in particular, $1\in uR$, so $u$ has an inverse.

Comment: Can you elaborate the final paragraph there? I'm a bit confused. If R is simple and it's ideals are 0 and R, why does uR=R not 0 or RR?

Comment: We have either $uR=R$ or $uR=\{0\}$. The latter case is excluded as $0\ne u\in uR$.